# Count rows if true then check if it it contains a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.like_log
(
    id integer,
    account_id bigint,
    match boolean,
    insert_timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

I have the following SQL query

```
select count(*) from like_log where insert_timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 hours' ) AND account_id = 1105399
```

How can I construct a SQL query that does the following?

First it would count the rows which the above query does, then if the count is more than 30, it will check if any of the rows has match = true. If it does it would return false, if the results don't contain a row that contains match = true then it will return true

if the count is less than 30 then it would return false

Comment: You have given us rules for `count(*) < 30` and `count(*) > 30`, but not for `count(*) = 30`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to know if both the following are true:

- The query returns more than 30 rows
- At least one of the rows is true.

How about this:

```
select ( count(*) > 30 and not bool_or(match) )
from like_log
where insert_timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 hours' ) and
      account_id = 1105399;
```

Comment: The requirement seems to be more than 30 rows and no match, i.e. `count(*) > 30 and not bool_or(match)`.

Answer (score 0):

With `case` to check for the conditions:

```
select
  case 
    when t.counter <= 30 then false
    else 
      case 
        when t.istrue > 0 then false
        else true
      end
  end result
from (
  select 
    count(*) counter,
    sum(case when match = true then 1 else 0) istrue 
  from like_log 
  where insert_timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 hours' ) AND account_id = 1105399
) t
```

It is not clear what happens when the count is equal to 30, so I included it in the case where count is less than 30.